# Is it possible to never use header guards in C/C++? If so, does this approach have any advantage?

Tags: c++, header-files

I have recently gotten into a project where the usage of header guards is forbidden as it is "bad design". Custom types are forward declared and headers are only included in cpp files.

This is the first project I have seen doing this and I find it quite uncomfortable to work with and if it were up to me I'd introduce the guards.

Using them has always been a given for me, so I don't even know how to argue against not using them other than highlighting the fact that it's uncomfortable. The project clearly compiles so in this case it's doable, but I'm left with a couple of questions:

- Are there other scenarios where it would make the development impossible?
- Does this style have a well-known benefit?
- Are there known open source projects using this approach?
- How would you convince the project leader to allow using guards?

Comment: what reason it gives for "bad design?"

Comment: and no, you can actually type all lines directly without any header file. But there is no point to do so.

Comment: If you ever have a situation where headers B and C both include header A, and both B and C need to be included by anything (e.g. by a source file or another header), then header A needs an include guard.    It is possible, with careful design, to avoid such situations - but generally the human effort of doing so (including fixing things up when some header is accidentally included more than once, or restricting content of headers pretty seriously) exceeds the effort of using include guards.

Comment: At very least, with this approach you won't be able to have accidentally a circular include

Comment: *"the usage of header guards is forbidden as it is "bad design""* They have a *very* unorthodox way of writing C++ at best, or are incompetent at worst.

Comment: If the project is essentially C code compiled with a C++ compiler this could work. This approach was probably designed twenty years ago by C programmers who were uncomfortable with C++ and never re-examined.

Comment: @PeteBecker C is where header guards originated

Comment: @Caleth -- my point was "C programmers **who were uncomfortable with C++**" and decided to impose draconian rules rather than understand it.

Comment: @PeteBecker that doesn't follow. C has header guards for the same reason that C++ has header guards.

Comment: @Caleth -- there were lots of things that C programmers moving to C++ decided they had to do that didn't make sense. I'm well aware that C and C++ header guards do the same thing, so you can stop telling me that. It has nothing to do with the point that I'm trying to make, which you keep missing. For many programmers that transition led to fear, uncertainty, and doubt, which in turn led to sub-optimal practices and guidelines.

Comment: @PeteBecker are you saying that people were so confused by the transition that they instigated practices that are a bad idea in *both* languages, or that merely questionable C practices became actively bad C++? That's what I don't follow from your point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Header guards are not "bad design". Refering to [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) and [Herb Sutter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herb_Sutter):

> [SF.8: Use #include guards for all .h files](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rs-guards)

I would love to see the people behind your new project to argue with Stroustrup and Sutter over what is "bad design" in C++.

Forward declarations are a great tool, yes. But certainly not an answer to all situations. How would that work? You only have pointers as class members? You meticulously ensure nothing is defined in a header file?

Comment: I won't argue that this "no include guards" policy should be challanged, but not by appeal to authority. Stroustrup and Sutter get plenty wrong as well.

Comment: My approach is born out of frustration with "local authorities" not allowing challenge to their ways, and to that I respond with "global authority" on a subject. However, if any real argument were presented, we could go into a technical discussion instead. Thank you for your comment though which I take to heart.

Answer (score 2):

I guess not including header in other header would cause maintaining list of headers in each translation unit (.cpp file).

If some dependency in one class on other is introduced, each header list is to be updated. Similarly, to take advantage of broken dependency, each list has to be updated too.

This does not look like a "good design".